# How to express vector multiply distribution by equation?

Tags: equations, distributions

1. I have a distribution of sale count of 24 hours , data would like `{0:20, 1:40, 2:22, .... , 23:9}`, let's say `Q`.
2. I have an hour array `[2,4,6,22]` as `a`, means `[2,4,6,22]` hours in a day.
3. I want to get sum of sale count in `a` .

The question is I want to present a formula by `sum_of_salecount_by_some_hours = sum(a * Q)` in latex.

May be something like:

```
{A = [a_0,a_1,..., a_i]  , a_i \in (0,1,2, ..., 23) , not allow duplicate , 0<=i<24  (A can be empty array)}

{Q is a distribution map A to B,  q_i \in [q_0, q_1, ...q_j] , q_j>=0 ,  j=23}

{B = A * Q}
```

I don't know much about math symbol, what' should I write ?

---

### The background

I am working in a online supermakert , my current work is to predict daily sale count of fresh goods.

The problem is every product may usually sold out/ stock out before a day end.
So the problem became restore the real daily sale count at first.

As you know, fresh things would easily decay, that's why we can't stock too much , which result in lack of normal data.

---

For example, I calculate the prawn stockout point(by hour) in last 147 days:

[image]

And average sale count(by hour) in last 147 days(`This is the distribution Q`):

[image]

If there are  the 7, 8 , 9 ,10 hour without stockout(I define stockout time < 15 minutes as not stockout) in today, i.e 2018-10-23 .

I can fix today sale count by

1. X_real = sum(real sale count in (7, 8, 9, 10))
2. X = sum(the history average sale count in (7, 8, 9, 10)) .
3. T = sum(the history average sale count in whole day)
4. Y = X_real/X * T

Here, `A` pick (7, 8, 9, 10) values from the distribution(picture 2) .

Now I want to express my steps in ppt ,I'd like to use latex to generate the equation. The problem is I don't know what is the proper way to express the `** step 2 **`  .

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Unfortunately your question is not as clear as it could be. What are you looking for? A plot of the distribution? Also I do not understand what array you are talking about.

Comment: @marmot  Not plot, sorry I am not English speaker, only know little math noun, may can't transfer my thought correctly .    I want to transform `result = sum(a * Q)`  to latex formula. As you see, `result = sum(a * Q)` doesn't look professional .

Comment: Does `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ \sum\limits_{h\in\{2,\dots 4\}\cup\{6,\dots 22\}}s(h)\]
\end{document}` go in the right direction? (Compile it e.g. with `pdflatex`.)

Comment: @marmot I think it's not this , please see my update.

Comment: It's really hard to guess. This is my last try: `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ \bigl\{A = [a_0,a_1,..., a_i]  ; a_i \in \{0,1,2, \dots, 23\} , 
a_i\ne a_j~\text{if}~i\ne j, 0\le i<24  \}\]
$Q$ is a map $A \mapsto B= [b_0, b_1,  \dots b_j]$ where $b_j\in \{0,\dots
23\}$,
\[ B = A * Q\;.\]
\end{document}`, and I hope you will find some more competent advice. (My hope, though, is that some variation of this code can serve as a basis of a LaTeX question.)

Comment: @marmot, I am not sure but think that the OP needs to get the result of the data and not to format the equation as LaTeX code, but to have an automated result with `\numexpr` (or better with `pgf` macros)

Comment: I appreciate that it is difficult for you to ask in English but, unfortunately, from what you have written it is not clear what you ware trying to do. Could you *edit* you question to add sample INPUT and sample OUTPUT?

Comment: @marmot  Thank you . I just wonder is there any symbol to express Q(the distribution) and the procedure A->Q -> B by correct mathematical representation .  As saw you code, it looks like there is no such a symbol ?

Comment: @koleygr @ Andrew I don't want it output the calculation result， just a correct equation would be fine, I have update the backgroud .

Comment: One way to cast step 2 in an equation is to run `\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\begin{document} 
$X= \sum\limits_{h\in\{7, 8, 9, 10\}}s(h)$
\end{document}` with `pdflatex`. As long as you say in your presentation that `s(h)` means the sales in hour `h`, that should do it IMHO. (I guess you will also be able to type an equation in powerpoint, but I can't tell since I never use this, I do all my presentations with latex/beamer.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think that OP has finded a solution using the comments.